# image to base64 JS converter doesnt work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I've found this converter https://github.com/rujs/Image-to-Base64-Converter/blob/master/index.html
and it's perfectly fine but it does NOT work in firefox.
can anyone tell me why?

This is the code:
JS

```
var reader = new FileReader(),
    rImg = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i,
    file;
reader.onload = function (e) {
    document.getElementById('preview').src = e.target.result;
    document.getElementById('base64').innerText = e.target.result;
};

function convert() {
    file = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];
    if (!rImg.test(file.type)) {
        alert("You must select a valid image file!");
        return;
    }
    console.log(file.type + ' :: ' + file.name + ' :: ' + file.size)
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

HTML

```
<h4>Image to Base64 converter</h4>
<img id="preview" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="" alt="Image preview" />
<input id="upload" type="file" onchange="convert();" style=""/>
<h4>Results</h4>
<textarea id="base64" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" ></textarea>
```

Comment: How it doesn't work? Does it show any error message? Does it convert the image to an incorrect string? What happens?

Comment: no errors. the thumbnail preview shows up but there's no base64 code in the textarea. in ANY other browser it works

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code to see where the problem is

Comment: YES. thanks man! innerHTML is the answer. i just missed it

Answer (score 0):

Need to change

document.getElementById('base64').innerText = e.target.result;

to

document.getElementById('base64').innerHTML = e.target.result;